# Want to combine data from multiple text files with some logic per line, then output to a csv file

Tags: powershell

Similar to what I would do with XLS VLOOKUP's, I want to use data from a first imported (text or csv) file, lookup additional data into another imported object, and append data from 2nd object to the available fields in 1st imported file.
Then write it all to a .CSV file.

I'm new to powershell, so any help is welcome.

I started already with this code

```
cls
#Date
$date = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMddHHmm #ss
#files
$ProductionORderFile = "C:\Mydir\prod-orders.txt"
$UOMFile = "C:\Mydir\uom.txt"
#file_Import
$ProductionOrders = get-content -Path $ProductionOrderFile
$UOMs = import-csv -Path $UOMFile -Delimiter '|' -header UOM_SKU, UOM_UOM, UOM_UOMT, UOM_Qty, UOM_StdUOM, UOM_StdUOMT, UOM_EAN, UOM_kg, UOM_kgT
#main_loop
foreach ($line in $ProductionOrders)
    {
    $PO_ProdOrder = $line.SubString(0,10)
    $PO_ProdOrderSKU = $line.SubString(11,10)
    $PO_ProdOrderCust = $line.SubString(21,8)
    $UOM_Found = "false"
    $DLUOMQTY = 0
    foreach ($UOM in $UOMs)
        {
        If ($PO_ProdOrderSKU = $UOM.UOM_SKU -And $UOM_UOM = "KAR")
            {
            $UOM_Found = "found"
            break
            }
        if ($UOM_FOUND <> "found")
            If ($PO_ProdOrderSKU = $UOM.UOM_SKU -And $UOM_UOM = "LTP")
                {
                $UOM_Found = "found"
                break
                }
        if ($UOM_FOUND <> "found")
            If ($PO_ProdOrderSKU = $UOM.UOM_SKU -And $UOM_UOM = "DIS")
                {
                $UOM_Found = "found"
                break
                }
        }
        if ($UOM_FOUND = "found) 
            { 
            $DLUOMQTY = $UOM.UOM_qty 
            }
        $SavePath = "C:\Other\Temp\2207\rapid-sap-uom2" + "_" + $date + ".csv"
```

So, after this step, I want to save my line with all data from 1st file (prod-orders), preferably by column, and then add some columns from 2nd file uom as per above logic .

How to proceed ?

many thanks in advance for guiding a new user.

Comment: Well honestly it looks like you can leverage Join-Object cmdlet [link]( https://github.com/ili101/Join-Object/blob/master/README.md ). Anyway in your code you can use build custom object [pscustomobject] with the data you need, Sort-Object in order to sort data and Export-CSV to export to file

Comment: It would help if you'd show part of the (sanitized) input files and your expected output file.